# Splitting python lists

Tags: python, list

I'm a newbie , I've written a tokenize function which basically takes in a txt file that consists of sentences and splits them based on whitespaces and punctuations. The thing here is it gives me an output with sublists present within a parent list.

My code:

```
def tokenize(document)
    file = open("document.txt")
    text = file.read()
    hey = text.lower()
    words = re.split(r'\s\s+', hey)
    print [re.findall(r'\w+', b) for b in words]
```

My output:

```
[['what', 's', 'did', 'the', 'little', 'boy', 'tell', 'the', 'game', 'eggs', 'warden'], ['his', 'dad', 'was', 'warden', 'in', 'the', 'kitchen', 'poaching', 'eggs']]
```

Desired Output:

```
['what', 's', 'did', 'the', 'little', 'boy', 'tell', 'the', 'game', 'eggs', 'warden']['his', 'dad', 'was', 'warden', 'in', 'the', 'kitchen', 'poaching', 'eggs']
```

How do i remove the parent list out in my output ?? What changes do i need to make in my code inorder to remove the outer list brackets ??

Comment: Why do you want to remove the outer brackets? You have a list of sublists.

Comment: I don't want sublists to be present in my output actually.

Comment: Then you'll end up with a tuple (with `( )`). Are you trying to print it out in a specific manner?

Comment: No I want them as individual lists :/

Answer (score 2):

> I want them as individual lists

A function in Python can only return one value. If you want to return two things (for example, in your case, there are two lists of words) you have to return an object that can hold two things like a list, a tuple, a dictionary.

Do not confuse how you want to *print the output* vs. what is the *object returned*.

To simply print the lists:

```
for b in words:
   print(re.findall(r'\w+', b))
```

If you do this, then your method doesn't return anything (it actually returns `None`).

To return both the lists:

```
return [re.findall(r'\w+', b) for b in words]
```

Then call your method like this:

```
word_lists = tokenize(document)
for word_list in word_lists:
    print(word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
print ','.join([re.findall(r'\w+', b) for b in words])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an example, which I guess is not much different from the problem you have...

where I only take a certain part of the list.

```
>>> a = [['sa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['dad', 'des', 'kkk']]
>>> 
>>> print a[0], a[1]
['sa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] ['dad', 'des', 'kkk']
>>>
```